# Wordpress translation to Hindi not working at the Admin-end

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, hindi

I did the following.. I copied language files i.e. hi_IN.mo and hi_IN.po to wp-content/languages folder. Then i made changes to  wp_config.php file, which is located in root folder.  I replace `define (‘WPLANG’, ”);` by `define (‘WPLANG’, ‘hi_IN’);`

Next, I went to Admin > Settings > General and chose Site Language=> hi_IN and saved it. Then i reloaded the website but it didn't not translate anything to Hindi. In .po file I can see translation such as:

```
msgid "Title"
msgstr "शीर्षक"
```

and

```
msgid "Tags"
msgstr "टैग"
```

but it does not show the translation at the back-end. The only translation i can see is for Contact Form 7 plugin which I believe is coming from the plugin itself, which means that the WP is set to have hi_IN as the default language. I am not sure why the back-end is not showing other core translations which are placed in the hi_IN.po and/or hi_IN.mo files. Please help if you know something about it. Website is http://jogindernagar.com.

Comment: I think the admin side is separately translated.  Do you have the admin translation file?  Looking at [the French translations](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/fr_FR/branches/3.9/messages/), there's `fr_FR.po` and `fr_FR.mo`, but also `admin-fr_FR.po` and `admin-fr_FR.mo`.

Comment: That's the problem I think. I don't see any admin-* files in the [Hindi translations](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/hi_IN/branches/3.3/messages/). I think i will have to create those files manually.